# C Reentrant Functions

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I have been researching and messing around with reentrancy/thread safety mainly because of a few concepts I am working on implementing.  I have come up with a theory, and was just wondering if anyone who has experience with re-entrancy issues could give their insights and knowledge on the concept...

Considering that the main problem lies when a function is being called via multiple threads (and a lot of the examples used when explaining these issues tends to even come from a signal interrupt calling the method while already in action) while that method is using local static and/or global data resulting in multiple calls attempting to change and/or manipulate the data in question.  That being said, the main advice for creating re-entrant functions is to ensure that this type of data is not used or when it is used have a mutex and/or semaphore locking mechanism protecting the read/write access to said data.  Now the locks would generate thread-safe functions, but does not guarantee a re-entrant function.  Now I know the following concept kind of goes against the above noted advice I have read, but I am curious to see if directly going against said advice can provide a fruitful method of ensuring re-entrant functions?

```
int some_func(int someIndexParam)
{
    static bool isActive = false; // start it off as false, no other instances calling it immediately
    if (isActive)
        return ALREADY_RUNNING;
    isActive = true;

    // DO ALL YOUR WORK HERE

    isActive = false;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

In the above concept, I am using one of the big "no-nos" in order to actually determine whether or not it would be safe to continue.  Now I know that this could still potentially lead to a race condition in the rare circumstance where such a function is called almost back-to-back with another call to the same function where-as the isActive value may not be appropriately updated in time to stop the second call from proceeding, but this I would consider to be a small factor unless the function is quite frequently called by a large number of threads, but I am curious to hear other's opinions on this method of handling re-entrancy issues?

Thanks

Comment: I won't enter the plane steered by this function.

Comment: I don't see how the initial call would ever get beyond the if statement. The way it is currently set up would eject any thread trying to get in.

Comment: "I am curious to see if directly going against said advice can provide a fruitful method of ensuring re-entrant functions" - no, it can't. Follow the advice. There's not much point trying to make a function only kind-of re-entrant. Besides, this method wouldn't make a function "re-entrant" in any meaningful sense, if the intent is to just make it unusable by more than one thread at a time.

Comment: Note that in your code sample the compiler is free to reorder your statements anyway it pleases. For instance, it can move the final assignment to `isActive` earlier, before the work is finished, or even omit the two assignments altogether, assuming that your work code doesn't use it.

Comment: The size of a race condition is unimportant.  They either exist or they don't.  And if they exist, they will cause you trouble at some point.

Additionally, the rules for threading and compiler optimizations are such that you'll see that buggy behavior more often than you would expect.  For instance, the compiler is not required to immediately let other threads know about changes to a variable unless you specifically mark the variable as being shared between threads.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR: it's a **big no-no** for a reason.

Multiple reasons in fact:

1. Compiler is free to rearrange things widely, as long as so called "observable behavior" as **specified** by the language is preserved. Language specification allows it to completely remove isActive assignments. And good compilers **will do** that!
2. No, it won't "potentially lead to a race condtition", it **is** a race condition. There is no "potentially" and no "leading". And remember that computers are capable of executing multiple billions operations per second (even your smartphone is), and successful programs are typically run significantly more than once and typically on significantly more than one computer. So even if probability of some event seems extremely remote, like once in trillion times, it is virtually certain it will happen, and will happen way sooner than you think.

This code is wrong for either multithreading (use mutexes or other proper synchronization primitives) or reentrant singnal handling (use proper sig atomic types, and use proper singal unmasking, etc.)

Comment: Do note that the compiler has to be able to prove that `isActive` isn't aliased anywhere else (which it may very well be able to do) in order for it to be able to optimize it away completely.

Comment: Yes, aliasing analysis must be able to enumerate all possible aliases (quite probably it can do that in this case) and show that observable behavior would not change if it elided asignments to this variable. If fact there is more stuff to take care for, like memory barriers, atomicity of operations, etc. That's why coding semaphores/mutexes is hard and unless one's an expert and know perfectly well what they are doing, one's advised to use readymade stuff, provided by such experts.

Answer (score 2):

What you have done is create a make-shift [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex). Using mutexes is a common and valid and technique to protect shared resources. As you realized, as implemented yours is flawed and may fail to prevent invalid accesses in "rare" circumstances. Do not feel bad as that kind of code is notoriously difficult to get right. Do not fall into the trap of thinking concurrent accesses of resources is unlikely. Problems like the above produce horribly difficult to debug problems. Mysterious failures that only occur on random alternate Tuesdays or demoing for an important client.

All this is difficult. An over-zealous compiler might optimize out setting your flag because all paths through the code un-set it anyway. Why do the extra work? Declaring isActive as volatile will prevent the compiler from optimizing away your protection but that does not stop hardware which may issue writes out-of-order. The reason that kind of protection is a "no-no" is that it is hard. You have to understand a lot of platform specific issues such as [memory barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) and [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) instructions.

TL;DR
You have an excellent idea, but a better implementation is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting idea; but perhaps with a few small issues.

First, an assumption:

```
#define true (-1)
#define false (0)
```

Then the question code might be suitable for a system with a single processor running multiple threads, which only performs a (thread) context switch when a blocking function is encountered.

Otherwise, it is somewhat dangerous.  For example, for a system with a single processor that performs a context switch "on the clock", it is quite possible that

```
       if(isActive)
```

would be executed by a specific thread, where 'isActive' evaluates to false.  But before that thread can execute

```
       isActive = true;
```

the thread is switched out of the CPU, allowing other threads to run.  If one of those threads comes into the same codepath, it will find

```
        if(isActive)
```

still evaluates to false.  Now you have two threads running in the function.

The question code would be functional (even for a multiple CPU system) if it used 'atomic operations'; which would allow the code to perform both the conditional check, and the set operations using a single operation.  While atomic operations are not portable, they are available on most all OS/compiler platforms (in various forms).  The gcc compiler used to offer atomic operations as library functions; but now they are **['built-in' gcc functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)**.

```
int some_func(int someIndexParam)
   {
   static bool isActive = false; 

   if(true != __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&isActive, false, true))
      return ALREADY_RUNNING;


   // DO ALL YOUR WORK HERE

   isActive = false;
   return SUCCESS;
   }
```

The question code is a good start.  And as stated, it is always better to write the code so that it is fully re-entrant, in a way that will not block a thread in any way.  However that is not always possible.

Comment: Even in your first case (single active thread, context switches on blocking calls only), this may not work because the compiler is allowed to optimize the `isActive` variable out of the compiled code.

Comment: First, `true` and `false` are C++ keywords. But if you're using C-89 don't define such constants. And do not do condition checks (`if`, `while`, `until`) by comparing to bool literals or even worse macros.

Comment: @seb, thanks for that clarification.  I am at a disadvantage when it comes to C++.  I live strictly in the world of C, with a little assembly; where (as you mentioned), such assumptions must be clarified.

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of this question I'm going to assume you don't do anything within signal handlers other than perhaps queue up an event for later processing.

Then if your program is single-threaded the code is totally unneeded and should be removed.

If your code is multi-threaded, then your code has a race condition. Multiple threads could read the current, unset value for `active` simultaneously and then both proceed to execute the non-reentrant code. It may seem to work fine in testing, but it *will* break, and probably for one of your customers at the most inconvenient time.

Your options are to do proper multi-thread checks using a mutex or atomic operation (test-and-set), OR to make the function non-reentrant by contract which means your application is responsible for not making reentrant calls.